# Ember Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Unable to find fixtures for model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, fixtures

I have my index page where i show a list of invoices where the user can click to create and edit them, i am using DS.FixtureAdapter in my adapter

The problem is that i get this error

*Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Unable to find fixtures for model*

If in my model i reopen the class like this, everything works fine

```
Invoice.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id          : '1',
      name        : 'Invoice num 1',
      transactions: [1]
    }
  ]
});
```

So i assume that i am doing something wrong in my template where i am saying if there are not invoices show me "no invoices..."

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h3>View Invoices</h3>
        <ul class="invoices-listing">
            {{#each invoice in model}}
            <li>
                {{#link-to "invoices.show" invoice}}
                    {{invoice.name}}
                {{/link-to}}
            </li>
            {{else}}
            <li>no invoices… :(</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <h3>Edit Invoices</h3>
        <ul class="invoices-listing">
            {{#each invoice in model}}
            <li>
                {{#link-to "invoices.edit" invoice}}
                    {{invoice.name}}
                {{/link-to}}
            </li>
            {{else}}
            <li>no invoices… :(</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      Invoices: {{InvoicesCount}}
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      {{#link-to "Invoices.create" class="create-btn"}} Add Invoice {{/link-to}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes Index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('fattura');
  }
});
```

This looks like a problem only when i start the ember server because for instance if i start creating and deleting invoices and i want to delete all of them the index page shows correctly "no invoices..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll always need to set up fixtures even if you want to start with no records. Ember still needs somewhere to go look for them and will error if you don't at least have a fixture with an empty array.

So you can just start your project with this in your model:

```
Invoice.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: []
});
```